# Follow image to mouse with rotation on Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, game-physics

[image: Follow image to mouse with rotation on Javascript]

How make Santa follow to mouse with rotation and own speed, not mouse speed?

Where mouse now - it's destination, where go santa with own speed.

Santa rotate with speed.

How can I do this?

[Demo code](https://playcode.io/376?tabs=game.js&player.js&output)

game.js

```
var canvas, ctx, player

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
  ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" )
  resizeCanvas()

  player = new Player( 
     ctx, 
     canvas.width / 2, 
     canvas.height / 2 + 100 
  )

  window.onresize = resizeCanvas
  canvas.onmousemove = mousemove
}

function mousemove( e ) {
   player.x = e.clientX * devicePixelRatio
   player.y = e.clientY * devicePixelRatio
}

function render() {
   ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height )
   player.draw()
}

function step() {
   render()
   requestAnimationFrame( step )
}

init()
step()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not trivial task with rotation.

Modified version with some magic: [**demo**](https://playcode.io/santa?tabs=player.js&output)

For `distance` used Pythagorean theorem.

Player moving to forward (by current rotation).

```
  class Player {
    constructor(ctx, x, y) {
      this.x = x
      this.y = y

      this.dest = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      }

      this.width = 200
      this.height = 200
      this.velocity = 12
      this.angularVelocity = 7
      this.rotation = 0

      this.ctx = ctx

      this.image = new Image()
      this.image.src = "//habrastorage.org/files/447/9b4/6d3/4479b46d397e439a9613ce122a66a506.png"
    }

    draw() {
      this.ctx.translate(this.x, this.y)
      this.ctx.rotate(this.rotation + 4.7)
      this.ctx.drawImage(
        this.image,
        -this.width / 2, -this.height / 2,
        this.width, this.height
      )
      this.ctx.rotate(-this.rotation - 4.7)
      this.ctx.translate(-this.x, -this.y)
    }

    distance(target) {
      let data = {
        x: target.x - this.x,
        y: target.y - this.y
      }
      data.len = Math.sqrt(data.x * data.x + data.y * data.y)
      return data
    }

    rotate(dt) {
      let path = this.distance(this.dest)
      let target = Math.atan2(path.y, path.x)

      let delta = this.rotation - target
      if (delta > 0.1 || delta < -0.1) {

        var _delta = delta
        if (_delta < 0) {
          _delta += Math.PI * 2
        }

        if (delta < -Math.PI || (delta > 0 && delta < Math.PI)) {
          this.rotation -= _delta / this.angularVelocity
        } else {
          this.rotation -= (_delta - Math.PI * 2) / this.angularVelocity
        }

        // Reduce character rotation into the -PI thru PI range
        this.rotation = (this.rotation + 3 * Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI
      }
    }

    step() {
      let distance = this.distance(this.dest).len
      if (distance < this.width / 1.5) {
        this.draw()
        return
      }

      let vel = distance / 15

      if (vel > this.velocity) {
        vel = this.velocity
      }

      this.rotate()

      this.x += vel * Math.cos(this.rotation)
      this.y += vel * Math.sin(this.rotation)

      this.draw()
    }

  }
```